# A group $G_1$ isomorphic to a subgroup and a quotient group of $G$

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, direct-product, quotient-group

Let $G$ be the direct product of two groups $G_1$ and $G_2, G:=G_1 \times G_2$. Then we can see that $G_1 \times 1$ is a normal subgroup of G and $G_1 \times 1$ is isomorphic to $G/(1\times G_2)$. In other words, $G_1$ is isomorphic to a (normal) subgroup and a quotient group of $G$.

Conversely,  given two groups $G$ and $G_1$ such that $G_1$ is isomorphic to a (normal) subgroup and a quotient group of $G$, could we get another group $G_2$ such that $G \cong G_1 \times G_2$?

Comment: No, if $G = C_{n^2}$ ($n>1$) is a cyclic group of order $n^2$, then $C_n$ is isomorphic to both a subgroup and a quotient of $G$, but clearly $G$ is not a product of $C_n$ with something else (since both factors would have to be cyclic and $C_{n^2} \not\cong C_n^2$.

Comment: @arkeet Thank you. How about requiring $G_1$ ismorphic to a normal subgroup of $G$?

Comment: Hmm? Every subgroup of $C_{n^2}$ is normal.

Comment: @arkeet Oh, yes. Thank you very much.